# GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableW for variable BootOrder fails with error ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, msdn, uefi

In our code during initialization of our product we always try to get efi variable **BootOrder** on EFI systems using function **GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableW** ([description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfirmwareenvironmentvariablew)).

```
 g_EFI_Environment->GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable_fn = (GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableFunc)GetProcAddress(
        Kernel32Module, "GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableW"
        );
...
ReturnLenght = g_EFI_Environment->GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable_fn(L"BootOrder",
    EFI_GLOBAL_VARIABLE,
    Buffer,
    sizeof(WCHAR) * BUFFER_SIZE);
```

But we discovered a case when it fails with error 203 (ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND) on HP laptop.
As I know variable **BootOrder** should exist on all EFI systems. But here it fails for some reason.

Does anybody know any reason of such behavior?

Can this be caused by some BIOS security settings or Windows policies?

Comment: Have you tried booting linux on that system and checked the content of /sys/firmware/efi/efivars?

Comment: No, we don't have such a possibility, because we don't have access to pc with a problem

Comment: @MiSimon it could help to check whether this variable exists or not, am I right?

Comment: yes, if some Windows security solution is hiding it.

Comment: The remarks in the document describe why this error occurred, please check.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfirmwareenvironmentvariablew



The exact set of firmware environment variables is determined by the boot firmware. Please check the BIOS version.



If the specified environment variable was not found in the environment block, GetLastError returns 203.
If the token passed to GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableW is called through LogonUser, please check the last parameter of LogonUser.